# Incrementing a date by one day but somehow decremented month by 1 at same time

Tags: java, android, xml, date, calendar

I made a function that was supposed to add one day to the date string parsed, it worked like a charm except it's decrementing the month by one value per function call. I don't know why it's decrementing that way, I just wanted to increment the day by one.

Here's the fx :

```
private void setTarikh() throws ParseException {
    FragmentJadual parentFragment = (FragmentJadual) getParentFragment();
    int lastTarikh = parentFragment.hariArray.size() - 1;
    String tarikhNewData = parentFragment.hariArray.get(lastTarikh).getTarikhHari();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd / MM / yyyy");
    Date d = dateFormat.parse(tarikhNewData);
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.setTime(d);
    calender.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd / MM / yyyy");
    String output = sdf1.format(calender.getTime());
    mNewDay = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mNewMonth = calender.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mNewYear = calender.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mTarikhTv.setText("" + mNewDay + " / " + mNewMonth + " / " + mNewYear);
}
```

I really tried looking at other functions that had problems but I can't even find a hint. Please help, at least to confirm that this function itself is true. I hate bugs but love them at the same time..!

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
.parse(
    "23/01/2020" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" )
)
.plusDays( 1 ) 
.toString()
```

> 2020-01-24

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

As others said, your likely problem is the crazy counting used by the `Calendar` class, running 0-11 for months January to December. One of *many* reasons to **never use `Calendar`** class.

The terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java were supplanted years ago by the industry-leading *java.time* classes.

## *java.time*

To parse a string in an format of day-month-year separate by the `/` character, define a formatting pattern with the `DateTimeFormatter` class, and parse as a `LocalDate`.

```
String input = "23/01/2020" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2020-01-23

Add your day increment.

```
LocalDate dayAfter = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;
```

> dayAfter.toString(): 2020-01-24

This has already been discussed *many* times on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android.]

Comment: Thank you bro T_T I feel a long way more for me in programming reading this comment

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
mTarikhTv.setText("" + mNewDay + " / " + mNewMonth + " / " + mNewYear);
```

Use

```
mTarikhTv.setText(output);
```

Besides this, it's not a problem or bug, it's a normal behaviour. If you try to look inside `Calendar` class you will find Month start here from 0-11 meaning 0-JANUARY and 11-DECEMBER.

```
System.out.println(Calendar.MARCH);
Output: 2 // Instead of 3
```